# Identify the cell which the mouse clicked on in WPF

Tags: wpf, grid, cell

What is the right way to identify the coordinate of each grid cell (row, column) in order to know if mouse clicked a particular cell in WPF? (from the code behind, dynamically without a button)

Comment: Can you post some of your code along with what you've tried so far, please?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you want to achieve? I think if you draw Grid on Canvas, you can easily get the co-ordinates. Give a try and update the post with code snippets.